# 2010 Ford Fusion won't start

Tags: ford, starting, fusion

My 2010 Ford Fusion won't start. I have checked it out really close and have even changed the starter. I finally called the place I bought it from and they said to turn on the key, turn the steering wheel all the way to the right until it was forced against the end and to hold it there, then to turn off the key, and then turn the key back on. All this while holding the wheel to the right. It works. What could the issue be?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about ford fusions, if I was to take a guess I'd say that a micro sensor is triggered to bypass the regular ignition starting

Comment: Had the sane problem it was the ignition fuse